# Django custom field validator vs. clean

Tags: django, validation, forms, field

I would like to create TodayOrLaterDateField() which would subclass DateField() field as I am using this condition in many places. The purpose of this field would be avoiding putting dates from the past.

What is the most straightway way of doing this? I am confused with validator vs. clean method.
I've tried with clean() but when comparing value to datetime.date.today() I am getting "compare unicode object to date" error.

I'm using Django 1.3

Comment: show the code that's giving the error.

Answer (score 30):

Validators only validate, they don't return the improved format;
Clean methods both validate and return a (sometimes amended) value.

I think the way to go here is to just use a DateField with a validator as a inherited class of DateField with a default_validators set.

```
import datetime
from django.core import exceptions
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def validate_date_today_or_later(value):
    'Place this in validators.py and import it to keep your model a bit cleaner'
    if value < datetime.date.today():
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('Date must be today or later'))

class TodayOrLaterDateField(models.DateField):
    default_validators = [validate_date_today_or_later,]
```

edit:
You can apply the same validator to your form fields as well if you just want it there and not in your whole app.

Comment: The first sentence explains it all. Thank You D4V360!

Comment: What I don't understand is when and where are `validate` and `clean` actually called, in other places of django..

Comment: I think the last part should actually be:
default_validators = models.DateField.append(validate_date_today_or_later)
This will include the existing DateField validators.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `models.DateField` and override `to_python` method. Didn't tested on Django 1.3 but should work.

```
import datetime
from django.core import exceptions
from django.db import models

class TodayOrLaterDateField(models.DateField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(TodayOrLaterDateField, self).to_python(value)
        if value < datetime.date.today():
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(u'Date must be today or later')
        return value
```

Comment: The condition would apply in frontend only. Admins are allowed to use dates from the past, so I wouldn't go with models here. (yeah, sorry, didn't mention that). Will try with to_python() and subclassing a forms.DateField. Thanks!