# Django: How to validate a birthdate entry as over 18

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, backend

Probably a silly question, but what would be the easiest way of validating a date field form entry as being over 18 years ago in Django?
(For a birthdate entry, validating age)

Comment: try using a combination of DateField and a write a custom validator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/fields/#DateField,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374275/django-custom-field-validator-vs-clean also has some things that you can start from and modify to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cleaned method in form class,
Like this:

```
from django import forms

class BirthDateForm(forms.Form):
    birth_date = forms.DateField()

    def clean_birth_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['birth_date']
        ...
            Traitment (do the delta with datetime.now and data)
        ...
        if birth_date_delta < 18 :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Access forbidden !")
        return data
```

Comment: What if your user is in a different timezone and it's their birthday?